# Drupal page--front.tpl.php redirection issue

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have a drupal 7 site with a page--front.tpl.php that acts as a splash screen. When i enter my site address like www.mysite.com and press enter i m redirected to the splash screen that is perfectly normal. Now, i want to redirect the user to the real www.mysite.com (i.e by bypass the splash screen or page--front.tpl.php) that is my page.tpl.php if a user clicks a link on the splash screen page.

Your help is highly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Just set another page up as a home page that you go to once you've gone past the splash screen and either set up a link to it to click on or use Javascript to redirect automatically.

If you want a link:

`<a href="YOUR_HOME_PAGE_URL">SPLASH_SCREEN</a>`

If you want automatic redirect:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function delayedRedirect(){
    window.location = "YOUR_HOME_PAGE_URL"
}
</script>

<body onLoad="setTimeout('delayedRedirect()', 3000)">
```

Change the number to change the time it takes before the page is redirected.

EDIT:

If your splash page is index.html then add the Javascript between the  tags. On your  tag add the onload function.

Change YOUR_HOME_PAGE_URL to the page you want to redirect to.

This code is dead simple and literally can't not work.

Comment: Its not a special node, thats just the landing page of my website.It doesnt have any node id. I hope you understand

Comment: Edited again. If you still can't make it work then start a chat and send me a link.

Answer (score 0):

There is a module in project application queue: [Splashify](http://drupal.org/sandbox/chrisroane/1423456)
,queued [here](http://drupal.org/node/1425392)

Its an active application. You may either wait for it to become a full project or contribute to it. It would provide you a cleaner implementation.